# Tomcat in debug mode restarts whever I try to change:

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, tomcat

Well, I'm developing a project with: JPA + Maven + Spring + JSF 2 + Primefaces + Tomcat 7 in Eclipse IDE.

I start my TOMCAT in DEBUG mode and I hope that I can change any piece of code and keep testing my software. The problem is when I try to change any piece of code, my tomcat is restarted automatically and I lose all the data in memory and I have to start tests from begining again.

How can I avoid this restart? Is there some way ?

This is the log of tomcat reload:

```
Abr 27, 2014 1:04:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
Informações: Reloading Context with name [/odontonew] has started
Abr 27, 2014 1:04:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Informações: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
19647 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] INFO org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl - closing
Abr 27, 2014 1:04:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
Grave: The web application [/odontonew] registered the JDBC driver [org.postgresql.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Abr 27, 2014 1:04:45 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
Informações: validateJarFile(/home/ronaldo/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/odontonew/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Abr 27, 2014 1:05:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
Informações: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
20 [Thread-5] INFO org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
22 [Thread-5] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.6.10.Final
24 [Thread-5] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - hibernate.properties not found
25 [Thread-5] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - Bytecode provider name : javassist
26 [Thread-5] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
35 [Thread-5] INFO org.hibernate.ejb.Version - Hibernate EntityManager 3.6.10.Final
```

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly in that you don't want tomcat to apply your changes until you decide to _manually_ restart?

Comment: No, i would like that this change take affect without restart. In desktop application (using tomcat too) i don't need restart when i'm in DEBUG MODE.

Comment: Then I think [this article](http://blog.redfin.com/devblog/2009/09/how_to_set_up_hot_code_replacement_with_tomcat_and_eclipse.html#.U10yaK2Sy04) may be helpful.